# Get metric distance between two points via a PostgreSQL/PostGIS request

Tags: postgresql, postgis, srid

I have a question about the use of postgreSQL/postGIS.

I would like to display markers on a map (stored in a database) which are some distance away from the user (coordinates given to the request).

The type of the field of the markers is POINT (I store lat/long).
The user position is detetermined by the Google Map API.

Here is the actual request :

```
SELECT * FROM geo_points WHERE ST_distance(ST_SetSRID(geo_points.coords::geometry,4326),ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(45.0653944 4.859764599999996)')) > 65
```

I know (after some research on internet) that the function ST_distance gives me the distance in degree between markers and the user position and that I test the distance in km.

I think I have to use the function ST_tranform to transform the points in metric coordinates.

So my questions are :
- what is the SRID for France
- how can I make this dynamically for the entire world according to the user position ?

I also kow that the function ST_within exists and that could do this. But I anticipate the fact that later, I could need the distance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

ps: there are maybe solutions in other post, but all the answers I have found during my researches were not really meeting my needs.

Comment: based on [this](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html), ST_Distance — For geometry type Returns the 2-dimensional cartesian minimum distance (based on spatial ref) between two geometries in projected units

Comment: try [ST_Distance_Sphere](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, pay attention to the axis order of coordinates used by PostGIS, it should be long/lat. Currently [you are searching in Somalia](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=4.859764599999996N+45.0653944E). Swapping to the coordinates, [you would be searching in France](https://maps.google.com/maps?espv=2&q=45.0653944N+4.859764599999996E).

You can use a geodesic calculation with the [geography type](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography), or use geodesic functions like [ST_Distance_Spheroid](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html). With the geography type, you may want to use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) for higher performance.

Here are `geo_points` 65 m away or less from the point of interest in France (not Somalia):

```
SELECT * FROM geo_points
WHERE ST_Distance_Spheroid(
    ST_Transform(geo_points.coords::geometry, 4326),
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(4.859764599999996, 45.0653944), 4326),
    'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]') < 65.0;
```

However, it will be very slow, since it needs to find the distance to every geo_points, so only do this if you don't care about performance and have less than a few thousand points.

If you change and transform `geo_points.coords` to store lon/lat (WGS84) as a `geography` type:

```
SELECT * FROM geo_points
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    geo_points::geography,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(4.859764599999996, 45.0653944), 4326)::geography,
    65.0);
```